# Calculating Memory offset of any Section of a Win PE File from Disk offset

Tags: debugging, portable-executable

Suppose I have a PE file(E.G. Notepad.exe). Suppose when the file is saved in hard-disk, the .text section of notepad.exe is at 0xabcdefgh offset.

So, how can I calculate/predict the offset of `.text` section when the same executable `(notepad.exe)` will be loaded into memory at the time of its execution, assuming ASLR is not enabled?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PE files are not position independent. Instead, they have a preferred load address, and if the OS is unable (because the address space is already used, or because ASLR is in effect) to load it in this address, it has to relocate it. See here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Relocations

So, if ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) is not enabled, it should load at the offset specified by the preferred load address specified in the header. This may not be the case for DLLs, but for executables it should be.

You can get more info on the file format here:

http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?fc=5

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Assuming ASLR is not there, How can I calculate exactly where all sections will be loaded in memory?? I've read this article,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx..It says "The offset of an item in the disk file may differ from its offset once loaded into memory. However, all the information is present to allow you to make the translation from disk offset to memory offset"

Comment: The relevant section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx is _"Relative Virtual Addresses"_. _"To convert an RVA to an actual address, simply reverse the process: add the RVA to the actual load address to find the actual memory address. Incidentally, the actual memory address is called a Virtual Address (VA) in PE parlance. Another way to think of a **VA is that it's an RVA with the preferred load address added in**."_ VA is what you're looking for. So you have to get the RVA for the .text section from the PE file and add it to the preferred address from the PE file.